# searching one string array for another

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm new to writing java and have a question I have to finish for college. 
I have done everything the question asked me to do so far except the last part where I have to type a name in and if the name matches the one that is in the string array it will calculate values.Been stuck on it for 2 hours now, please help

```
      System.out.println();
  System.out.print("Enter the candidate's name: ");
  candi[0] = keyIn.nextLine();


  for(int i = 0; i<votes.length; i++)
  {
     if(candi[0].equals(names[i]))
     {

        for(int h = 0; h<votes.length; h++)
           {

              if(votes[i] == votes[h])
              {
                 same = same+1;
              }
              else if(votes[i]<votes[h])
              {
                 less = less+1;
              }
              else if(votes[i]>votes[h])
              {
                 more = more + 1;
              }
           }
     }
     else
     {

           System.out.print("Name does not match, enter again : ");
           candi[0] = keyIn.nextLine();
     }
  }
```

Comment: what error you getting and what expected o/p you want?

Comment: it will always go to the else statement, I've typed the word in exactly how it is in the array, i'm not sure what o/p means

Comment: o/p means "output"

Comment: Shouldn't your first for loop  until names.length instead of votes.length? Also, can you post the names array as well?

Comment: just try using trim() like this in the if condition:

candi[0].trim().equals(names[i].trim())

Comment: post the votes as well as names array if you can.. so that I can quickly give u the solution.

Comment: String[] names = {"Dunne","Doherty","McGlynn","Grant","Sweeney","McHugh","Gibbons","O'Neill"};
      int[] votes = {0,13,28,6,6,29,15,5};
      double[] avg = {0.0,12.7,27.5,5.9,5.9,28.4,14.7,4.9};

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are only checking one name for each input (name at `i`). You need to loop through all the names to check whether the one entered matches one in the array. To solve this I wrapped the whole thing in a `while` loop and separated the match-check to its own little `for` loop:

```
    String[] names = {"Dunne","Doherty","McGlynn","Grant","Sweeney","McHugh","Gibbons","O'Neill"}; 
    int[] votes = {0,13,28,6,6,29,15,5}; 
    double[] avg = {0.0,12.7,27.5,5.9,5.9,28.4,14.7,4.9};

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter the candidate's name: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in = scan.nextLine();

    boolean containsName = false;

    while (true) { // continue asking for names until one mathces

        // Check if name is present
        for(int i = 0; i<names.length; i++)
        {
            if(in.equals(names[i]))
            {
                containsName = true;
                break; // break the for loop
            }
        }

        // do something if name is present, continue if not
        if(containsName) {
            System.out.println("Calc!");
            break; // break the while loop
        }else {
            System.out.print("Name does not match, enter again : ");
            in= scan.nextLine();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I guess you are looking for something like this :**

> where you can do some operation when name entered by the user is found
>   in the array of candidate names.

**Working Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class match {
    match() {
        Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in); //for taking input
        String candi[] = new String[1];         //for storing name input
        String candiNames[] = { "ab", "bc", "cd" }; //String array of candidate names
        Boolean found = false; //flag to check if name found or not

        System.out.print("Enter the candidate's name: ");
        candi[0] = keyIn.nextLine(); //taking input

        for (String n : candiNames) { //looping 
            if (candi[0].equalsIgnoreCase(n)) { //matching string (ignoreing case)

                found = true;
                // do the working here for anything you wish to do on match
                // found
            }

        }
        if (found == true) {
            System.out.println("Match found ");

        } else if (found == false) {
            System.out.println("Match not found for : " + candi[0]);
        }
    }

}

public class StringName {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new match();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

- **Match Found**

[image]

- **Match not Found**

[image]

> I hope I helped :)